Animate Properties
I animated a sphere to rotate by using the following code inside the Z rotation box in the object properties #frame/50.
This worked and when the animation played it rotated the object.
Then I changed it to #frame/90 and again it worked with no issues.
However at some point it stopped working and I reset it to 0
now there is a zigzag arrow on the right of the z rotation box and I cannot change it back to the diamond for key framing. The padlock is showing it as unlocked.
how do I return the setting back to normal without deleting the object and doing it all over again. 

it's ok , you have to right click and delete the single driver.
